# Python BeautifulSoup Parsing Table Yahoo Fantasy Football data

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize

For fun, I'm trying to scrape some data on my Yahoo fantasy football league for player transactions.  This is my first run with mechanize and beautifulsoup and I'm having trouble printing out specific data.  What I'm looking to extract are players name, if they were added 'To Waivers' and also the date.  I'm able to get the first part, but I'm unsure how to get the date.  First is a sample of the HTML and the 2nd part is my code:

```
        <table class="Table Table-mid Tst-transaction-table">
                <tr>
        <td class="Grid-u-1-12 Ta-c"><span class="F-icon Block Fz-lg F-positive Cur-h" title="Added Player">&#xe035;</span><span class="F-icon Block Fz-lg F-negative Ptop-med Cur-h" title="Dropped Player">&#xe033;</span></td>
        <td class="Fill-x No-pstart" colspan="2">
            <div class="Pbot-xs">        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/24963" target=sports onclick="pop(this)">Dwayne Harris</a>
        <span class="F-position Fz-xxs">NYG - WR</span>
        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/24963/news" class="yfa-icon playernote playernote-recent" data-ys-playerid="24963" data-ys-playernote-view="notes" target="_blank" id="playernote-'.24963.'"></a>  <h6 class="F-shade Fz-xxs"> Waiver </h6></div>
                    <div class="Pbot-xs">        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/6791" target=sports onclick="pop(this)">Benjamin Watson</a>
        <span class="F-position Fz-xxs">NO - TE</span>
        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/6791/news" class="yfa-icon playernote playernote-recent" data-ys-playerid="6791" data-ys-playernote-view="notes" target="_blank" id="playernote-'.6791.'"></a>  <h6 class="F-shade Fz-xxs"> To Waivers</h6></div>
        </td>
        <td class="Ta-end">
            <div class="Grid-h-top Nowrap Fz-xxs">
    <span class="Grid-u">
      <a class="Tst-team-name" href="/f1/313652/10">TeamName2</a> 

      <span class="Block F-timestamp Fz-xxs Nowrap">Nov 20, 4:03 am</span>
    </span>
    <a class='Grid-u' href='/f1/313652/10'><img class="Avatar-sm Mstart-med Grid-u" src="http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/fantasy/nfl/img/icon_01_100.png" alt="avatar"> </a>
</div>
        </td>
    </tr>    <tr>
        <td class="Grid-u-1-12 Ta-c"><span class="F-icon Block Fz-lg F-positive Cur-h" title="Added Player">&#xe035;</span><span class="F-icon Block Fz-lg F-negative Ptop-med Cur-h" title="Dropped Player">&#xe033;</span></td>
        <td class="Fill-x No-pstart" colspan="2">
            <div class="Pbot-xs">        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/7306" target=sports onclick="pop(this)">Darren Sproles</a>
        <span class="F-position Fz-xxs">Phi - RB</span>
        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/7306/news" class="yfa-icon playernote playernote-recent" data-ys-playerid="7306" data-ys-playernote-view="notes" target="_blank" id="playernote-'.7306.'"></a>  <h6 class="F-shade Fz-xxs">Free Agent </h6></div>
                    <div class="Pbot-xs">        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/24262" target=sports onclick="pop(this)">Joique Bell</a>
        <span class="F-position Fz-xxs">Det - RB</span>
         <span class="F-injury Fz-xxs" title="Probable">P</span>
        <a href="http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/24262/news" class="yfa-icon playernote playernote-old" data-ys-playerid="24262" data-ys-playernote-view="notes" target="_blank" id="playernote-'.24262.'"></a>  <h6 class="F-shade Fz-xxs"> To Waivers</h6></div>
        </td>
        <td class="Ta-end">
            <div class="Grid-h-top Nowrap Fz-xxs">
    <span class="Grid-u">
      <a class="Tst-team-name" href="/f1/313652/3">TeamName1</a> 
      <span class="Block F-timestamp Fz-xxs Nowrap">Nov 19, 1:30 pm</span>
    </span>
    <a class='Grid-u' href='/f1/313652/3'><img class="Avatar-sm Mstart-med Grid-u" src="http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/fantasy/img/profile_48.png" alt="avatar"> </a>
</div>
        </td>
```

Code:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

username = 'my-username'
password = 'my-password'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
br.open("https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/313652/transactions")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form["username"] = username
br.form["passwd"] = password
response = br.submit()
html_scrape = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_scrape, "lxml")

for lines in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'Pbot-xs'}):
    players = lines.find('a').get_text()
    status = lines.find('h6').get_text()
    if (status == ' To Waivers'):
        print "%s was dropped" % players
```

I've tried using the find() function on the Table, but I can't figure out how to grab the text data I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to give you a proper answer without being familiar with a yahoo fantasy football page, but I can tell you that if you're trying to 'point' BeautifulSoup towards a specific div, you ought to use BeautifulSoup's `select` feature like so:

```
for lines in soup.select("div#pBot-xs"):
    players = lines.find('a').text
    status = lines.find('h6').text
    if status == 'To Waivers':
        print "%s was dropped." % players
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a little tricky because in fantasy sports, you can drop a player but not necessarily add a player.  I approached this by going through the list and adding Player Names and date in order.  Players had to match the ' To Waivers' attribute.  Then I set a try/catch block to ensure the previous object in the iteration had a corresponding Player.  This would ensure my dictionary values be Player > Date > Player > Date, etc

I then iterated over the dictionary and formatted the print in the way I wanted:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

username = 'username@yahoo.com'
password = 'password'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
br.open("https://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/313652/transactions")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form["username"] = username
br.form["passwd"] = password
response = br.submit()
html_scrape = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_scrape, "lxml")
index = 1
dropped = {}

for players in soup.select("table > tr > td > div"):
    player = players.find('a').get_text()
    try:
        if (players.find('h6').get_text() == ' To Waivers' ):
            dropped[index] = player
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    time = players.find('span',{'class':"Block F-timestamp Fz-xxs Nowrap"})
    if (time != None):
        try:
            nullplayer = dropped[index - 1]
            time = time.get_text()
            dropped[index] = time
        except KeyError:
            pass
    index += 1

count = 1
for items in dropped:
    if (count % 2 == 0):
        player = dropped[items - 1]
        time = dropped[items]
        print "%s dropped on %s" %(player, time)
    count += 1
```